# No build menu in Visual Studio when opening an existing cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions

I am new to Visual Studio. I just followed a tutorial and successfully wrote and ran a simple program. But after I closed Visual Studio and double click the cpp file I just wrote. I can't find the build menu in the Visual Studio. Could anyone tell me how to open and run the existing cpp file? I need to do some debug and don't want to begin a new project and copy the code again and again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to open more than the `.cpp` file alone.

Make sure you open the whole project or solution (`File/Open/Project` - `.sln`, `.vcxproj`, `.vcproj`). Double clicking on a `.cpp` file will open that file only.

Then you should be able to build the project (or hit <kbd>Ctrl-F5</kbd>).

Comment: To be more precise, open the file that ends in .sln or in .vcxproj, they are the project file that instruct VS how to build your program and what files it needs

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem suddenly in vs 2022 in one of my projects c#.
When I opened other project it looks ok and the build menu is available.

When inspecting the project, I found by accident  that the project **is opened as folder** (open folder).
I closed the project then select '**open project or Solution'** and every thing is ok.

So the root issue is that project is opened as folder.

Comment: Hello @M.Hassan could you take a look to this question please? I've some difficulties to open the project because there isn't a sln or other files recognized by VS as a project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77140823/option-build-solution-in-visual-studio-2022-doesnt-appear

Comment: Hello @GennaroArguzzi, I answered the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150040/3142139). Let me know if this can resolve your issue